# Embedding EMGUCV as resource

Tags: vb.net, dll, emgucv, embedded-resource

I'm working on an application that requires EmguCV. I've gotten EmguCV dlls to load, but I'm stuck on another folder for EmguCV. The x86 folder contains a bunch of vital dlls (such as ffmpeg) and is required. But whenever I load my application, it says it cannot find cvextern (because it's searching in a x86 folder, that isn't there.) I added a folder to my resources with the same name and dlls in it, but it still cannot find it.

I've searched for a long time, with no results.

Is there anyway to embed EmguCV as a resource?

Comment: How are you referencing `EMGU.CV`? Did you install it as a `NuGet` package?

Comment: Yes. But, since NuGet just compiles all the dlls/dependenies into the folder, I've got all the dlls. Do I need something else? Thanks

Comment: No, you shouldn't need anything else. Could you please edit your post and include the exact error message?

Comment: In case it helps, here's a simple [Face Detection](https://github.com/morphx666/FaceDetection) program using `Emgu.CV`. You'll need to configure the `CameraPlug` constructor of the `Form_Load` event handler to setup your IP camera parameters; not really necessary just to test that `Emgu.CV` loads without any errors.

Comment: I'm not sure you guys understand. I don't want any external files I have to load up for my exe. I want to embed all dlls as a resource. I can't embed a folder as a resource, and this folder contains dlls required for Emgu.CV so I can't embed it. Is there any single dll or anything?

Comment: Well, in that case you may want to take a look at tools like [SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/#merging-dlls) or [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).